# npm broken after installing via brew

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, homebrew

So i'm installing node, npm and cordova+ionic on my mac (High Sierra) and it's giving me this issue:

```
Julime-Air:~ julime$ brew install node
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/node-9.3.0_1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/julime/Library/Caches/Homebrew/node-9.3.0_1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring node-9.3.0_1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.3.0_1: 5,125 files, 49.6MB
Julime-Air:~ julime$ npm install npm@latest -g
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/usr/local/bin/npx -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
+ npm@5.6.0
updated 1 package in 16.966s
Julime-Air:~ julime$ npm -v
5.6.0
Julime-Air:~ julime$ npm install -g cordova ionic
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansistyles
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansistyles' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.ansistyles.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/julime/.npm/_logs/2017-12-15T22_50_54_958Z-debug.log
```

tried reinstalling but no luck

Edit:
Running as sudo does not help.

Edit2:
Installing Node via mac installer does also not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install ghost fails with code EPERM errno -4048 syscall rename (on Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677801/npm-install-ghost-fails-with-code-eperm-errno-4048-syscall-rename-on-windows)

Comment: @tech4him this does not seem to be the same error nor is that fix from op relevant for me. Downgrading npm for perfoming any install is also not an option.

Answer (score 1):

After having some trouble removing that mac-installer-node, i think this fixed my problem:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
brew doctor
brew link --overwrite node
```

If you had the same issue, please comment if this helped.

Comment: I would not advise overriding permissions for `/usr/local` directory @Zanna did a great job explaining it in answer to [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261326/is-it-safe-to-chown-usr-local) which is UNIX system as well so similar rules apply to macOS as well.